# Extendig codeigniter Mail library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm extending the CI mail library for logging proposes, but when I send the mail, it goes trough the PHPMail a not trough the SMTP server that I have been declared in `config/email.php`.

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

   protected $logDir;
   private $_clr_subject = '';
   private $_clr_msg = '';

   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->logDir = 'logs/mail';
   }


   function send($auto_clear = TRUE) {

       $result = parent::send(FALSE);
       //After send I will save all the log stuff
       $this->_saveLog(true);

       if ($result && $auto_clear) {
        $this->clear();
       }

    return true;
   }
   [...]
}
```

So, I know that probably I'm doing something wrong, but I do not what...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure the library read a config file to set anything except for the charset which is in config/config.php

Comment: Actually, if you have the config file `email.php` you can save the SMTP (or whatever you want) preferences, see http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences-in-a-config-file. Thanks for the feedback ;)

Comment: Maybe it's a documentation mistake or it was a removed feature, but I don't see anything loading a config file in the library.

Comment: Finally the Dfriend solution worked. thanks for the help anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because your constructor does not have the same form as the Email class which defined this way.

```
public function __construct(array $config = array())
{ ...
```

So try this for the MY_Email constructor

```
public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
   parent::__construct($config);
   $this->logDir = 'logs/mail';
}
```